# select text object in visual mode in vim command

Tags: vim

I want to use the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin to align latex tables. However, I like to write rules within the table as follows:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
  Column 1 & Column 2 \\
  \midrule
  Value 1 & Some very long value \\
  2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
```

If I use the Tabular plugin "as intended", only the lines with the values will be aligned, but the header row won't.

I can achieve the desired result using the [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) plugin by selecting all lines with the same indentation (a text object that is selected with `ii`) and then call the `:Tabularize` command. However, I struggle to squish all of this into a command. My current approach is:

```
nnoremap <Leader>at :V ii Tabularize /&<CR>
```

But the syntax is incorrect, and i get an error when trying to call it. I could not find any hints on how to select the lines and then call a command using this type of mapping. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My approach had 2 issues:

- the ii from the vim-indent-object plugin does not seem to work with the n**nore**map - it works with a regular nmap.
- the `:` was at the wrong place
- the space between the `V` and the `ii` was incorrect.

The correct mapping therefore is:

```
nmap <Leader>at Vii:Tabularize /&<cr>
```

Comment: `nore` is short for "non-recursive". A non-recursive mapping uses the original meaning of the keys in the right hand side, without expanding any mapping or abbreviation. This is usually what you want for most mappings but it will obviously break if you want to use other mappings in your mappings. In those cases, dropping `nore` is the way to go.